# JavaScript variable becomes null when toUpperCase() applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, null

Modifying a jQuery plugin, I have lines of code as follows:

```
var currentread = (self).find('.c'+a).html();
//currentread = currentread.toUpperCase();
$('#output').html(currentread);
```

With the middle line commented out, the code works fine. The contents of the div with the class 'c[1-n]' is displayed in #output. Uncommenting the middle line to convert this to upper case, however, generates the error 'currentread is null' for that line.

I must be doing something stupid here, but this doesn't seem to make sense. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you converting html to upper case? Did you mean to use `text()`?

Comment: the variable cannot "become null" when you call `.toUpperCase()` - it must have been null beforehand.

Comment: Post you html too. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: josh.trow: Ah, changing it out to text() did the trick. I did think it a bit odd that the original plugin author chose html() but honestly I'm new to jQuery so didn't know about text(). Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is is simply the case that `currentread` is null? You could change it to:

```
currentread = (currentread || "").toUpperCase()
```

so that toUpperCase is always called on a string.

Comment: currentread isn't null until that middle line is entered, hence the confusion.

Comment: How do you know it isn't `null` already? `jQuery(".no-items-have-this-class").html()` will return null. You won't get an error if you pass `null` into `.html()`, but you will if you try to call a method on it.

Comment: Because setting #output to its value displays it correctly. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Could the code be called twice, once when the jQuery selector matches nothing, and once when it does? It could break the first time, then display your expected output the second time. It's suspicious that it works when you use `.text()` instead of `.html()`, since with an empty jQuery set of elements, `.html()` will return null, but `.text()` will return an empty string which you can call `.toUpperCase()` on. It seems likely that `(self).find('.c'+a)` didn't match any elements, you could check that by putting `console.log((self).find('.c'+a))` on the line before.